# Emit a DateTime in the Map function of MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

My map function looks like this:

```
map = function()
{
   day = Date.UTC(this.TimeStamp.getFullYear(), this.TimeStamp.getMonth(), this.TimeStamp.getDate());
   emit({day : day, store_id : this.Store_Id}, {count : 1});
}
```

TimeStamp is stored as date in the database, like this:

```
{ "TimeStamp" : "Mon Mar 01 2010 11:58:09 GMT+0000 (BST)", ...}
```

I need the "day" in the result collection to be stored as a date type as well, but it's stored as long (Epoch ticks) like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "day" : 1265414400000, "store_id" : 10}, "value" : { "count" : 7 } }
```

I tried changing the emit to something like this but didn't help:

```
emit({day : {"$date" : day},...)
```

Any ideas as to how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date.utc is going to return miliseconds from epoch.  So when you put your data back into the DB, you can use for example:

```
 new Date(dateAsLong)
```

and it will be stored as the BSON date format.

earlier than mongo 1.7 it will show up in your hash as:

```
 "Mon Mar 01 2010 11:58:09 GMT+0000 (BST)"
```

1.7+ it will appear as:

```
 ISODate("2010-03-01T11:58:09Z")
```